# How do I cut a string in half?

Tags: php, string, explode

I want to cut a string in half, and get the first half of the string to be one value the second half to be another.

The string is `$_GET['s']` it has a couple of words and in the middle of them four blank spaces.

I want to get the words before the blank spaces and the words after the blank spaces.

E.G:

```
pizza    soda
```

```
echo "$food;"   ==> pizza
echo "$drink;   ==> soda
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list($first, $second) = explode('    ' /* 4 spaces */, $_GET['s']);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$value = explode('    ', $_GET['s'], 2);

echo $value[0]; // food
echo $value[1]; // drink
```

Reference: http://php.net/explode

Comment: it should be noted that if there's any risk of the string containing more than one set of four spaces to limit the call: `explode('    ', $_GET['s'], 2)`